# Best way to implement Drag and Drop Dashboard items in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, widget, dashboard

I'm trying to make a dashboard application, and I'm trying to create the layout rules for it and such and I'm not sure the best way to go about it. Originally I had a custom grid control, so I could add my custom controls to it easily enough. It worked in the sense that if you initially put stuff there, it was fine. But I want to implement a drag and drop facility in it and it kinda doesn't really like that.

The biggest annoyance is just detecting what position my mouse is on in terms of what row and column its in in the grid. So So I thought instead of a grid, I could use a Canvas, and just manually measure the grid slots. But I'm not sure if there's a better way. I'd like to mimic how on android, you can have widgets for the home screen and you can drag and drop them around the screen. I'd like it to just be like that essentially.

When dragging, I'd like have a green rectangle move instead of the thing and make it red if it overlaps with something else. Like I said, basically just like how android widgets work. I'd love some code examples since I'm new to WPF. If you've got any more general suggestions as well, that would be well appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

check out [blacklight](http://blacklight.codeplex.com/) and its newer version on [github](https://github.com/jogibear9988/Blacklight-Toolkit)

the dashboard demo is what you need to look at.

You may have trouble to compile the code, but simply by removing the silverlight projects you can get the WPF demo running.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question. Creating this answer for anyone else who stumbles onto this question looking for a WPF Dashboard. I couldn't find any other Dashboards with dynamic widgets out in the wild so I created my own and I am sharing for anyone else who needs a better solution. This sounds like what Gentatsu was looking for in his initial question.

You can find it here:
https://github.com/DustinBryant/WpfDashboardControl